# How to handle SQL table change in Android

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, events

I'm writing Android application consists of GUI part and broadcast receiver. Broadcast receiver could add new row into SQLite table, which is generally used by UI.

Problem: when UI part is running (on foreground), broadcast receiver can add new rows to SQL, but that row won't appear in GUI until my refresh() method called. However, I haven't any idea about how to inform foreground UI activity about this refresh necessity from background broadcast receiver OnReceive() method.

I have some experience in native Win/*NIX software development and tried to find something similar to events for Android, but had no success.

Am I going wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Why use a broadcast receiver? Is the SQLite table receiving data from other applications or remote services? If so, you should really use a content provider, which is a much easier and more robust way to handle databases in the background.

If you're displaying part of a table in the UI, then you probably retrieved a cursor from the table. You can register an observer on the cursor for the table, so that you're notified whenever the data backing the cursor changes.

Comment: BroadcastReceiver used to process new incoming SMS to track my banking notifications, so this is the only source for new rows for database.

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't help. I can receive cursor observer notifications when my application updates one of existing records in database, but I can't handle new records adding - handler was not called for new rows creation neither from activity, nor from broadcast receiver.  Can I handle new rows adding?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at CursorLoader for you UI which able to asynchronously update your content when it is chang/updated.

[How to use CursorLoader](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_loading-data_cursorloader/)

You will need to set the notification_uri.

```
cursor.setNotificationUri(context.getContentResolver(),your_notification_uri)
```

When these set of data is change/updated by your BraodcastReceiver, in the Broadcast Receiver sending the notify to the above notification url, the data in the UI will be updated accordingly.

```
context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(your_notification_uri,null);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use CursorLoader, because I'm using API level 10 (Android 2.3.4). I'll try to use cursor's observer, if observer doesn't help, try content providers instead.